# How to import csv files without header and missing values in the first row

Tags: r, fread, read.csv, read.table

I'm attempting to read csv files that do not have a header. Each file has 11 columns. If data for a variable is missing for a time, it is left blank. If the first row has all of the observations (values in all 11 columns), it is simple to read all of these files. However, if data is absent in the first row, the file is not imported correctly.

I tried with following code and even with `fread` also.

```
temp = list.files(path = "/home/DATA", pattern = "4.*", full.names = TRUE)

df <- lapply(1:length(temp), function(i) read.table(temp[i], header = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
```

For instance, the standard file looks like this:

```
 1007.0     14   25.0   23.6     92  18.61      0      0  297.6  351.7  300.9
 1000.0     70   25.0   23.4     91  18.51      0      0  298.1  352.1  301.4
  946.0    557   24.4   18.4     69  14.29      6      2  302.3  344.8  304.9
  895.0   1041   21.6   17.9     79  14.64     12      5  304.2  348.1  306.9
  850.0   1486   20.0    3.0     32   5.62     18      7  307.1  324.6  308.1
```

However, if data is missing for several levels or full columns then it is like
sample_data1

```
 1001.0     14
  968.1    304                                290     23
  934.6    609                                300     33
  850.0   1431   17.8                         260     23  304.8         304.8
  700.0   3069   10.6                         355     11  314.2         314.2
```

or sample_data2

```
 1004.0     64  -20.1                                     252.8         252.8
 1000.0     95   20.2                                     293.4         293.4
  950.0    533   21.8   15.8     69  12.02                299.3  334.6  301.5
  600.0   4333    1.0   -1.2     85   5.88                317.2  336.2  318.4
```

or some files are like sample_data3

```
 1000.0
  850.0
  700.0           8.3                                     311.6         311.6
  500.0
```

using above code sample_data1 is imported into 7 columns, sample_data2 is imported into 9 columns and sample_data3 is imported into 4 columns.
How can I import all these csv files in 11 columns and `NA` for the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `readr` library:

```
readr::read_csv(
  file,
  col_names = TRUE,
  col_types = NULL,
  col_select = NULL,
  id = NULL,
  locale = default_locale(),
  na = c("", "NA"),
  quoted_na = TRUE,
  quote = "\"",
  comment = "",
  trim_ws = TRUE,
  skip = 0,
  n_max = Inf,
  guess_max = min(1000, n_max),
  name_repair = "unique",
  num_threads = readr_threads(),
  progress = show_progress(),
  show_col_types = should_show_types(),
  skip_empty_rows = TRUE,
  lazy = should_read_lazy()
)
```

This function has a `na` argument where you can specify which values should be replaced by `NA`. The default is an empty field ("").

Comment: Could you kindly explain how I can read sample data1, sample data2, or sample data3 into 11 columns, as shown  in the first sample (standard file) above?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `read.csv` instead of `read.table`?
Use `read.csv`. This will replace blank rows and columns with `NA`'s and if you want spaces in place of `NA`'s then use `colClasses="character"`.

```
temp = list.files(path = "/home/DATA", pattern = "4.*", full.names = TRUE)
df <- lapply(1:length(temp), function(i) read.csv(temp[i], header = FALSE))

#To read blanks as spaces
df <- lapply(1:length(temp), function(i) read.csv(temp[i], header = FALSE, colClasses = "character"))
```

Comment: Tried with `read.csv` also but didn't work

Comment: I tried with all your 4 sample data and it works for me with `read.csv` but not with `read.table`.

Comment: did you check your csv files with blank rows and columns in excel? Are they well defined. When you open it in Excel, are there a total of 11 columns with and without blanks?

Comment: If I open the file in excel, all the values are coming in single cell.

Comment: are they separated by commas?? like this : 1001,14,,,,,,,,,
968.1,304,,,,,290,23,,,
934.6,609,,,,,300,33,,,
850,1431,17.8,,,,260,23,304.8,,304.8
700,3069,10.6,,,,355,11,314.2,,314.2

Comment: It is a data structure with 11 columns. Here no. of columns = no. of commas +1.
I think the problem is in the data, so I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Commas are not there only black space. Anyways I solved the issue by inserting header in each file using ```sed``` command.